# NodeJs - Sharing a list of categories across all pages

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a website where the navigation bar contains a drop down list which contains the following categories:

1. Web Development
2. Mobile Development
3. Desktop Development
4. Programming

Do i need to retrieve the above categories every time a new page of my application is requested. For example:

- For the home page i retrieve the categories from the database.
- For add product page i also retrieve the categories from the database.

I know that my approach is not efficient, Is there a better way to accomplish it.

Kindly note that i am using pug template engine

Thanks

Comment: you can store the navigation in json or javascript object form and pass it to the routes.

Comment: between if you want it more dynamic then database is good approach but the efficient way will be to create  a middleware that injects the navigation object from database for specific pattern. you will not have to do it yourself then.

Comment: what is the front-end technology that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

the better way to get what you want is using Redux, it lets you share variables above all the code. it's simply to implement.

you can see the documentation [here](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start)

Comment: In the mean time, i am learning NodeJs, I would like to focus on NodeJs and how to accomplish such a task in NodeJs. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: saving on local storage, if the component and use it where you need. you should put on a waiting list learn redux, is hellpfull